# Unnecessary use of extended slicing in python?

Tags: python, slice

Is there any point to using the extended slicing syntax if one doesn't specify the stride/step? I came upon a piece of code that uses an expression like this:

`x[0::,1::]`

where `x` is a numpy array (although I'm not sure that is relevant). This appears to be the same as

`x[0:,1:]`

using the basic slicing syntax. Am I missing something or are these uses of extended slicing here simply overkill?  Similarly, is there a use case for favoring an extended slicing with unit positive step `x[i:j:1]` over the simpler `x[i:j]`?

Comment: People do that to be explicit, but its overkill and adds unnecessary noise. In general, if you're going to use the default (in this case or in an argument to the method) its better to leave it out for brevity.

Comment: Thanks, gandu. I thought as much but wanted to check to make sure I wasn't missing something.